# .htaccess non-www to www and http to https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know this question has been asked and answered many times but I've spent the last 3 hours going through peoples answers and none have seemed to work just right for me.

I need some `.htaccess` code to do this:

If domain is `example.co.uk/$urlData` (only apply to main domain and no subdomains) rewrite too `www.example.co.uk/$urlData`

If HTTPS is not "on" and domain is primary (ie. no subdomains) then redirect to `https://www.example.co.uk/$urlData`.

I have to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` to test if HTTPS is off as `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` is not configured on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co\uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try and see if this will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've just uploaded it and get an internal server error

Comment: @JackTrowbridge Yes I had a typo in the last line. It was supposed to be `RewriteRule` I guess I was typing too fast.

Comment: @JackTrowbridge The way I have it is less code and accomplishes what you needed. Sorry about the typo which I corrected and will leave my answer if someone else wants to use it.