# .htaccess non-www to www and http to https redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For some reason my redirects are not working. I just want non-www to go to www and non-https to go to https. Here's what I've got. It's from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119684/htaccess-non-www-to-www-and-http-to-https).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: Here is my whole file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} Off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} blog.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/blog/$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.exmaple.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/blog/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What URL is not redirecting?

Comment: Anything that starts with http or does not have www. at the beginning. I have tested it so if it's not the script, then it is another issue.

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Is this your complete `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Okay, I've added the rest of the file @user82217.

Comment: Also, the site does break sometimes when I edit the code @anubhava

Comment: You introduced a `blog` subdomain (and subdirectory) that was not present in your original code - is this relevant to your question?

Comment: No, not really, but you asked if the script I provided was the whole file. It isn't so I provided the whole file just incase you thought it was relevant. @user82217

Answer (score 3):

> I just want non-www to go to www and non-https to go to https.

What you had initially was close, but it depends on how the SSL cert is managed. If the SSL is managed by a front-end proxy (eg. Cloudflare flexible-SSL/FREE option) then it maybe OK. However, if the SSL cert is installed directly on your server then probably not.

Try something like:

```
# Non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

# Non-SSL to SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

This assumes you only have `example.com` and `www.example.com`, and no other subdomains. However, in your edited code you make reference to a `blog` subdomain - this will be OK, provided you include the `blog` redirect first.

This is currently a temporary (302) redirect. Change the `R` to `R=301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK.

Make sure you browser catch is clear before testing.

### Summary

The complete code would look something like:

```
# Redirect blog subdomain to main domain (required?)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blog\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

# Non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Non-SSL to SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It is best not to edit between the `# BEGIN WordPress` blocks to avoid your custom code being overwritten by WordPress.

Only include the `RewriteBase` directive once in your code (only the last instance will do anything). Currently, the `RewriteBase` directive is not actually doing anything anyway, since you have no relative path substitutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting this together. You bring up a good point about the proxy. We do have a reverse proxy setup so that we can have a wordpress blog in the subdirectory of a windows server (on a linux server). So I'm not sure if that will interfere. Either way, I made a backup of the .htaccess file and added in your sample. Here's what happens: 1) if I go to a non-http url it redirects me to a 404 page on the windows server 2) if I try with https and non-www it does the same thing. I think you may be on to something with the way the SSL is setup, because I would not have factored that in.

Comment: Since you are getting a 404, presumably it's redirecting to the wrong URL? What URL are you requesting, what URL are you being redirected to and what is the desired URL?

Comment: I tried 2 types. 1) http://www.example.com/blog/postname - it redirected to https://www.example.com/notfound.aspx (windows host). The second 2) https://example.com/blog/postname - redirected to https://www.example.com/notfound.aspx @user82217